# What is happening when adding a number to the array element

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

**Example 1:**

```
Var arr = [1,2,3] + 1;

console.log(arr) // "1,2,31"
typeof arr // String
```

**Example 2:**

```
var arr = 5 + ["h","e","l","l","o"];

console.log(arr) // "5h,e,l,l,o";
typeof arr // String
```

Doing the above concatenate the number/string to the last/first element in the array. Would like to understand what happens here?

Comment: Are you sure you get `[1,2,31]` in your first snippet?

Comment: In first example the output is – "1,2,31". Proof – http://screencast.com/t/r1J0j5jo3RYG

Comment: @Max Thanks! updated now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you are using `+` (concatenation in this case ), it's applying **[`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString)** method to the array. So it's just concatenating with the result and not appending with last or first element.

> The Array object overrides the toString method of Object. **For Array objects, the toString method joins the array and returns one string containing each array element separated by commas**.
>
> **JavaScript calls the toString method automatically when an array is to be represented as a text value or when an array is referred to in a string concatenation**. (*[Taken from here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString#Description)*)

---

Check the following snippet all those are results the same.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3];

// all these are providing the same result 
// result of toString method
console.log(arr.toString())
// concatenation with empty string at end
console.log(arr + "")
// concatenation with empty string at start
console.log("" + arr);
```

Comment: Var arr = [1,2,3] + 1;

console.log(arr.toString() + "Hello")  ->  [1,2,3Hello]
typeof arr // Object

Comment: @KarthickManoharan It is the same actually, there is an typo in your question

Comment: If you notice the code in my comment above. Converting the array to string and doing the concatenation with the + operation the resulted output is still Array type.  @Max

Comment: @KarthickManoharan What JS engine do you use? Browser, OS? Because in Chrome, MacOS I see this – http://screencast.com/t/QgR3KoieCx

Comment: @KarthickManoharan I don't need to use instanceof or  typeof. In both cases it returns strings, it is obvious

Comment: @KarthickManoharan Did you read http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden I've posted in my answer? If not yet, just read it now :) It's very very helpful resource for JS devs

Answer (score 0):

To add an element to the array use one of this methods.

As @Pranav C Balan mentioned `+` operator try to concatenate 2 values. That's one of the most weird parts in Javascript. Here is a very helpful page with all of subtleties [JS Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/)

**Example 1:**

```
Var arr = [1,2,3];
arr.push(1)


console.log(arr) // [1,2,3,1]
typeof arr // object
```

**Example 2:**

```
var arr = ["h","e","l","l","o"];
arr.unshift(5);

console.log(arr) // [5,"h","e","l","l","o"];
typeof arr // object
```